# Enabling SSL on the ColdFusion 8 built-in web server

Tags: ssl, coldfusion

So I followed the instructions here with CF8 on winXP:

http://www.cfchimp.com/wordpress/2008/08/enabling-ssl-on-the-coldfusion-8-built-in-web-server/

and got the following error:

[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

On FF I get this error:

> **Secure Connection Failed**
>
> An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:9100.
>
> Peer reports it experienced an internal error.
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_internal_error_alert)

Also there is nothing in the CF logs.

Comment: fwiw it looks like others have had the same issue: forums.adobe.com/thread/52931?displayFullThread=true and did not find a solution..

Comment: Questions : Which browser are you using and have you tried other browsers ? Is SSL enabled in the browser ? And could you post the contents of your jrun.xml.

Comment: I tried chrome, Firefox, and ie.

Answer (score 0):

go to CF Admin, go to "Java and JVM" on left menu, in "JVM Arguments", add:

-Dcoldfusion.disablejsafe=true

restart CF, done